# update PHP 5.5 to 7.0 with Avada ThemeForest and WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, updates, php-7, php-5.5

I need to update PHP version to 7.0, but how can i do that?
 is it
possible to update it manually? i use avada ThemeForest and WordPress.
and my Web Host can upgrade it from controlpanel like Cpanel.

Is it possible to update it in FileZilla? 
I have read about the Htacess method, but it is confusing.
It looks like you have to either pay for it or get Cpanel or something.

Comment: You should probably contact your hosting provider for more information on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Does your hosting provider allow php upgrade on your end in the first place? If your hosting provider allows ssh access to your host, this [link](http://www.letmefix-it.com/2017/07/02/how-to-upgrade-php-5-x-to-7-0/) should help you. This is how I upgraded php running on my home server.